# Import multiple large sql dump mysql

Tags: mysql, windows

I want to import several .sql files into database using `source` command (mysql command line). But when I get this error:

```
source E:\Progs\Backups\DBs\file01.sql

ERROR:
Unknown command '\P'.
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sourc
e E:\Progs' at line 1
....
```

I used source command to import large files hundreds times but now I can not understand what I'm doing wrong. This is my system(I'm using XAMPP (Basis Package) version 1.7.3 :

- Windows 7x64
- MySQL 5.1.41 (Community Server) with PBXT engine 1.0.09-rc

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

**Edit:**
I tried this one, but same error:

```
source 'E:\Progs\Backups\DBs\file01.sql'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL sees the `\P` in `E:\Progs` as a command.  Because that command does not exist, it complains.

Forward slashes are understood in many cases.  Try:

```
source E:/Progs/Backups/DBs/file01.sql
```

Comment: Do you know any way to import 1000 file at once?

Comment: It may be safe to concatenate the files together.  The only times I've ever needed to do something similar, I wrote a quick shell script to go through all of the files and import them directly.  I'm pretty sure something similar could be done in a batch file, though you may have more luck with PowerShell.